# MKMapView removeAnnotation is not removing the selected annotation

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, mkmapview, mkannotation

When I call removeAnnotation and pass it a pointer to the annotation I had added, it is not removing the annotation...  Is this because it had made a copy of the annotation when I added it?

Thanks
Deshawn

Answer (score 5):

You could try this

```
nsarray *oldAnnotations=[self.mapview annotations];
[self.mapview removeAnnotations:oldAnnotations];
```