# How to remove my custom annotation from mapView?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

First of all this I assure you this is not an duplicate question. I have a map and I want to change my annotation coordinate from X direction if user change the region. My goal is achive to create my pins at the left side of view.

When I create my pin, I add it to my var pins: MyCustomPin also. However, in my regionDidChangeAnimated;

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {

    calculateZoomFactor()

    if isInLegalRegion() {
        //.....
    } else {
        mapView.setCenter(mapCenter, animated: true)
    }
    arrangePins()
}
```

and my arrangePins() func does ;

```
func arrangePins() {

    for pin in pins {
        let coord = pin.coordinate
        let title = pin.title!
        self.mapView.removeAnnotation(pin)

        let xCoord = self.mapView.visibleMapRect.minX + 250
        var newCoord = MKMapPoint(coord)
        newCoord.x = xCoord

        let newPin = MyPin(newCoord.coordinate, title)
        mapView.addAnnotation(newPin)
    }
}
```

So far so good. Although It seems very logical and simple, my old annotations does not remove from map. Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Remove old annotations from your `mapView `. Use `removeAnnotations ` method.

Comment: I am using remove annotations method as you can see.. However I can't remove all annotations.. self.mapView.removeAnnotation(pin) you  can see this code in my arrangePins() func

Comment: I do not want to remove all annotations.. Did not you read my comment ?

Comment: Maybe it's a million year old bug in MapKit, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876662/mkmapview-removeannotation-is-not-removing-the-selected-annotation#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing your pin from the mapView, but you are not removing it from your `pins` array. So - when you create a new pin, you are always basing its x coordinate on the original pins you added to the array (and subsequently removed from the `mapView`).

Similarly, you are adding a new pin to the mapView, but you are not appending it to your `pins` array. You are therefore never removing these new pins from the `mapView`, as you are only removing pins from the mapView as you loop through the `pins` array.

Your `arrangePins` method, for example, could look like this:

```
func arrangePins() {
    var newPins:[MyPin] = []
    for pin in pins {
        let coord = pin.coordinate
        let title = pin.title!
        self.mapView.removeAnnotation(pin)

        var newCoord = MKMapPoint(coord)
        newCoord.x = self.mapView.visibleMapRect.minX + 250

        let newPin = MyPin(newCoord.coordinate, title)
        mapView.addAnnotation(newPin)
        newPins.append(newPin)
    }
    pins = newPins
}
```

(To simplify things, I added new pins to a `newPins` array, and then used that to replace the `pins` array after the for loop.)

A couple things you might want to consider:

- Instead of maintaining your own array of `pins`, you could simply use `mapView.annotations` (of course this assumes that you are adjusting all the pins on the map, maybe you only want to adjust some specific pins)
- Rather than deleting and adding pins, why don't you just move pins? For example, the `arrangePins` method could look like this:

```
func arrangePins() {
  for pin in pins {
    var newCoord = MKMapPoint(pin.coordinate)
    newCoord.x = self.mapView.visibleMapRect.minX + 250
    pin.coordinate = newCoord.coordinate            
  }
}
```

Comment: I can not move my pins because there are different kind of pins in my map. And I just added a kind of a copy into my list. I tried firstly move my pin with title, however I got error. Then I try to remove and add new one. If I try what you write in your snippet I will just change the coordinates of my pins.. However mapView annotations coordinates won't be change.

Comment: I didn't realize before noob mistake about my array initialization. So thank you a lot :)

Comment: "If I try what you write in your snippet I will just change the coordinates of my pins.. However mapView annotations coordinates won't be change" -> I'm not sure what you mean to be honest. I assumed that your `MyPin` class subclasses `MKPointAnnotation`, i.e. your pins *are* `MKPointAnnotation`s, and therefore changing the coordinate of your pin will move it on the mapview.

Comment: let pin = myPin(pinPoint.coordinate, title)
    mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
    pins.append(pin)

 I add them to map and my array.. however when I change my coordinates of pins of my array, the they are not moving

Comment: Did you also remove pins you removed from the mapView from the pins array?

Comment: I have added code to my answer, hopefully that will help.

Comment: By the way I forgot to add that. pin.coordinate is get-only property. I cannot assign a new value. That's why pin.coordinate = newCoord.coordinate  This code gives build error

Comment: Ah ok, well that makes sense if your `MyPin` class needs to have a coordinate that is only gettable. Perhaps your `MyPin` class subclasses `MKAnnotation`. You could alternatively set it up to subclass `MKPointAnnotation` which has a `coordinate` property which is both gettable and settable.